# Anyone can give me a working sample of JSF2.0+richfaces4.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Anyone can give me a working sample of JSF2.0 + richfaces4.0?

I just upgrade from JSF1.2 + richfaces3.3 and lots of problems, the major problem is the `<a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.method}" />` seems not working, the page just flash once and the method is not actually called. I have been investigating this for more than 5 hours and still don't know how to solve this . :( crying...

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you define "not working?". I think we need a bit more information about your problem. Maybe you can expand your question and flag to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the richfaces source which includes example apps and run them on your own machine to learn and get a feel for JSF2 apps.

http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/stable

It's important to note that migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 isn't necessarily a trivial exercise. In other words, it might involve a fair bit of migration, especially when it comes to the AJAX and Composite Components side of things.

Comment: Add ing a link to the migration guide, as it is also an invaluable resource: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a post on getting started with JSF2 here: http://induceddevelopment.com/2011/12/06/getting-started-with-jsf2/

It is very easy to plug Richfaces 4 into this.  I hope to do an article soon outlining this.  However there is lots of information out there.